# Copy index of vector Elements with condition

Tags: vector, c++14, remove-if

I want to save the indices of my bool vector where the vector element is false.

I have the following code:

```
vector<bool> incumbent_solution; // (0,0,0,1,1,0,0)...
vector<int> I_minus_S(incumbent_solution.size());

auto it = copy_if(incumbent_solution.begin(), incumbent_solution.end(),
        I_minus_S.begin(), [&incumbent_solution](auto i) {if (incumbent_solution[i] == 0] return i; });
I_minus_S.erase(it, I_minus_S.end());
```

But it only stores True in my Vector and not the indices.
What is my lambda doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) works differently than you expected, it passes the actual element to the predicate and copies it into the second container if the predicate returns `true`.

If you want indexes, use a simple `for` loop:

```
std::vector<bool> incumbent_solution { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 };
std::vector<int> I_minus_S(incumbent_solution.size());

std::size_t last = 0;

for(std::size_t index = 0; index < incumbent_solution.size(); ++index) {
    if(incumbent_solution[index] == false)
        I_minus_S[last++] = index;
}

I_minus_S.erase(I_minus_S.begin() + last, I_minus_S.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector< bool >  vb = { 0,0,0,1,1,0,0 };
std::vector< int >   vi;

unsigned counter = 0;
for( bool b : vb ){
    if( !b ){
        vi.push_back( counter );
    }
    ++counter;
}

for( int& i : vi ){
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

`std::copy_if` accepts an UnaryFunction that should return `true` or `false`. It is better to use a simple `for`.

---

If you are demanding to use `algorithm` library, you can use `transform`

```
std::vector< bool >  vb = { 0,0,0,1,1,0,0 };
std::vector< int >   vi;

int counter = -1;

std::transform( vb.begin(), vb.end(), std::back_inserter( vi ),
                [&](const bool b ){
                    counter++;
                    if( !b ) return counter;
                }
               );
```

but the problem with that is, for `true` condition returns `0` to the index of `vi`. Although you can use `-1` and later remove them inside `vi`

```
                [&](const bool b ){
                    counter++;
                    if( !b ) return counter;
                    else     return -1;
                }
```

but still a simple `for` is a better solution.

Comment: yes, for loop is simple and clear